# ECLIPSE PHOTON:C program not running(Error: build command 'cmake' not foundFailure running cmake:

Tags: c, eclipse, error-handling, mingw

I just installed eclipse photon and installed the `minGW` compiler. I can't run any program. When I try to run my C program I get this error

> Error: build command 'cmake' not foundFailure running cmake

Comment: Then perhaps you need to install `cmake`.

Comment: can you add a little more detail? how are you starting your c program? are you importing a cmake project?

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment::Add your path, restart